# How to write save block code like this more elegant in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have a class `Creator` which will execute a block code for a number of times. I'm not sure how to write this in a more elegant way in Ruby.

```
class Creator
    attr_accessor :block
    def self.create(&block)
        @block = block
        return self
    end

    def self.for(number)
        0.upto(number) {
            block.call
        }
    end
end
```

And this is how I call it which I want to stay like this.

```
Creator.create{ 
  SomeModel.create!(@attr)
}.for(30)
```

Comment: I am sure you have your reasons, but what about `30.times { SomeModel.create!(@attr) }`.

Comment: Yeah, that's one option that I was looking at as well. But I'm trying to learn code/block in ruby and I'm planning to do some more in this class as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want instance methods, not class methods.  With the current code, you would get:

```
hello = Creator.create { puts "Hello" }
goodbye = Creator.create { puts "Goodbye" }
hello.for(1)   # Prints "Goodbye"
```

Assuming you don't want `block` to be changed afterwards, I would change `attr_accessor` to `attr_reader`.  I don't see much reason to even expose a reader, though — it seems that doing so would only lead to mischief.

```
class Creator
  # For compatibility with the old API
  def self.create(&block)
    return self.new(&block)
  end

  def initialize(&block)
    @block = block
  end

  def for(number)
    number.times { @block.call }
  end
end
```

This is just a syntactic sugar wrapper for blocks.  Perhaps a more generic name than `Creator` might be appropriate.  It might also be simpler to call `number.times { block.call }` directly.

Standard indentation for Ruby is two spaces.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done simply enough inline that I don't think the creator class is worth the trouble:

```
30.times.map { SomeModel.create!(@attr) }
```

`30.times` creates an Enumerator that yields 30 times, then `map` turns each yield into a new instance of `SomeModel`.

or, if you don't need the actual instances:

```
30.times { SomeModel.create!(@attr) }
```

Comment: apparently the OP wants the code to work by side-effects (not a great idea) and the `map` is not necessary.

Comment: @tokland, Thanks.  Edited.  When dealing with the database, it's all about side-effects.  What the OP wants done doesn't seem bad to me (although the heavyweight machinery to do it does).

Answer (score 1):

With `attr_accessor :block` you define a accessor for an instance.

You may use the variable `@block` directly:

```
class Creator
    def self.create(&block)
        @block = block
        return self
    end

    def self.for(number)
        0.upto(number) {
            @block.call
        }
    end
end


Creator.create{ 
  p 'here' #your SomeModel.create!(@attr)
}.for(30)
```

Or if you think you need an accessor:

```
class Creator
  class << self
    attr_accessor :block
    def create(&block)
        self.block = block
        return self
    end

    def for(number)
        0.upto(number) {
            block.call
        }
    end
  end
end


Creator.create{ 
  p 'here' #your SomeModel.create!(@attr)
}.for(30)
```

But there is no need of for and create. I would define only one method that accepts the number of executions:

```
class Creator
    def self.create(number, &block)
        number.times{
            block.call
        }
    end
end

Creator.create(30){ 
  p 'here' #your SomeModel.create!(@attr)
}
```